# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jQuery & jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, undefined-function, typeerror

I am trying to use the jQuery UI autocomplete widget but I'm getting the following error in Google Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery-ui.min.js:7
>   e.widget.refresh jquery-ui.min.js:7
>   (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.widget._create jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.Widget._createWidget jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   n.extend.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   e.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.widget._create jquery-ui.min.js:7
>   (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.Widget._createWidget jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   n.extend.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   e.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   (anonymous function) create:684
>   j jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   k.fireWith jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   n.extend.ready jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
>   I jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2

I include jQuery and jQuery UI in the header like so:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Client DB</title>
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/autogrow.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.mattni.cloner-0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/filter-years.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.filter.js"></script>
</head>
```

I then call the function at the end of my HTML like so (I've replaced some information which is sensitive to the client):

```
<script>

$(function(){
    console.log("You autocomplete me");
    var availableTags = ["Autofill 1","Autofill 2"];
    $("#ref").autocomplete({source: availableTags});

    $("#basis").autocomplete({source: ["Choice 1", "Choice 2"]});
    $("#brand").autocomplete({source: ["Possible option", "Unladen swallow"]});

});
</script>
```

This worked at one point and now suddenly it is now. I have scoured the web looking for anyone having the same issue. I can only find examples of people receiving one or two errors, not a long list like this. I get the same errors if I link to jQuery and jQuery UI on Google, so I know it's not an issue with the files.

Has anyone seen these errors before or know how to fix them?

Comment: Did you make any changes in the libraries you are using after which it stopped working and threw this error?

Comment: What is the version of jQueryUI you are using. Try changing it.

Comment: Please check for all the files you are including, are all they available. Make sure you are not getting `404 not found` error for the files you are including !

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9LKAB/ using the versions specified in the question (ignore non-existent formatting and notice there's no script errors thrown). Most likely a compatibility/browser version issue; try running it with different versions, or if none work -- include non-minified library files and debug.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it was a naming conflict in the jQuery list filtering plugin I was using ("jquery.filter.js"). I commented out the filter library and it resolved the issues.

Comment: Had the same issue. Turned out it was a plugin naming conflict as well. Thanks for sharing your findings.